# Why Lighthouse PWA Optimized Audit Error on My Site

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to audit my site using lighthouse but it is always error on PWA Optimized part. The errors are on "Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS" and "Contains some content when Javascript is not available".
But it is working fine on localhost.

Here is my site:
https://hrms.dxn2u.com:8888/hrmslite_test/index.html

[img]https://i.imgur.com/i7cooWa.png[/img]
[img]https://i.imgur.com/i3KOpxx.png[/img]

I am really appreciate for help...

Comment: you need to redirect http to https as it saids

Comment: What is that meant? How to do that? That message is not clear. There isn't stack trace on lighthouse.

Comment: that means you need to configure your nginx server, apache server, or whatever serve you have, to redirect all http traffic to https traffic